# image editing in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am going to create an app for iphone/ipad and I want to known which classes or methods are used for photo editing like blur image change background change effect etc...

```
@interface YouProjectName_ViewController : UIViewController {

}
```

Comment: What issue are you having with what you've tried?  I don't understand the UIViewController line - is that all you have?

Comment: Search the SDK for the `doMyWorkForMe` method.

Comment: I like the irrelevant and content-free code snippet to get around the quality filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the [GPUImage Framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) could help, to manipulate images.

> The GPUImage framework ... iOS library that lets you apply GPU-accelerated filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies. In comparison to Core Image (part of iOS 5.0), GPUImage allows you to write your own custom filters, supports deployment to iOS 4.0, and has a simpler interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIImage*)processImageRect:(UIImage*)image:(CGSize)size:(CGSize)originalSize {
    // Draw image1  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalSize);  
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)]; 
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}
```

This function will be helpful to you in your application.